# Call external js file function in Angular js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the external js file which has more functions.

I need to call these functions from angular controller.

For example: **external.js**

```
...
...
function fun() {
  ...
  ...
}
...
...
```

Controller: **acccountController.js**

```
myApp.controller('AddAccountController',function ($scope,AddAccountLoginServices,$location,localStorageService,$compile,toaster){
   ....
   ....

   $scope.getLoginForm = function(siteId,name) { 
            ...
            ...
            fun(); // This function from external.js file
   });

   ...
   ...

});
```

I have imported external.js before the acccountController.js. But it doesnt calling that function. And also i have not get any console error for this.

How to achieve this... Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you imported the external js in the angular module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**: gave wrong answer, my bad. the following example works.

your external file should like this:

```
var doSomething = (function () {
  "use strict";
   return {
      test: (function () {
        return 'test';
      }()),
      test2: (function () {
        return console.log('test 2');
      })
   };
}());
```

and in your controller you call your scripts function:

```
console.log(doSomething.test);
```

or

```
doSomething.test2();
```

i learned something too, thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am newbie for angular js. if i put var external = require('assets/plugins/form-generation/js/external.js'); in controller means, i get this console error "ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Comment: i'm sorry, require is node.js only ... my mistake. ...still trying ;)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @nilsK, you define a [self invoking function](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/). And then reference to it via `window` object. For example -

```
(function functionName(){
    Do Something Here...
})();
```

And then,

```
window.functionName();
```

And if your are using AngularJS,

```
$window.functionName();
```

Comment: $window should be injected, for angular

Answer (score 1):

I have similar situation and I did not have to make it self invoking function. Including the external js file into the html and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where is you call $scope.getLoginForm()?. I think you never call it. So fun() is not called, so you not see any thing. You need call $scope.getLoginForm(). Two way to call
In HTML `<button ng-click="getLoginForm()"></button>`
Or in Javascript `$scope.getLoginForm()`
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a global instance of the function.

Add a line:

var abc= new funcName();
at the end of the File and you can use this line (var abc= new funcName();) in your controller to invoke any methods from this file by using abc.methodName.