# How can I call a function inside an angular expression from another js file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Alright so I have a function that does a rotation of a string call `rotateString()` in a file call rot-n.js.

How can I access this function to be called on an `ng-model` in AngularJS to show the encrypted code in my view?

here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="cipherApp">
<head>
  <title>ROT-N CIPHER</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rot-n.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>


<textarea rows="8" cols="45" ng-model="cipher.encryptIn"></textarea>  <input type="number" min="0" max="25" ng-model="cipher.rotN">
<p>{{rotateString(cypher.encryptIn, cypher.rotN)}}</p>
```

Comment: So I found an answer to my question located here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697493/call-external-js-file-function-in-angular-js-controller thanks!

Comment: mark as answer if my answer has helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function on scope that invokes the encryption function:

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.rotFn = function (din) {
        var dout;
        rotateString(din,dout);
        return dout;
    };
});
```

Then use the `ng-change` directive to invoke the function:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
     <textarea rows="8" cols="45" 
         ng-model="cypher.encryptIn"
         ng-change="cipher.rotN=rotFn(cypher.encriptIn)">
     </textarea>  

    <input type="number" min="0" max="25" ng-model="cipher.rotN">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access that function when you are using another controller, You should go for [Factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) or [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

or using Event: listen with $scope.$on and you send it with $scope.$broadcast or $scope.$emit

**Sample for factory:**

```
angular.module('share',[])
    .factory('dataService', function() {
       var _dataObj = {};
       return {
        dataObj: _dataObj
      };
    })

    .controller('One', function($scope, dataService) {
      $scope.data = dataService.dataObj;
    })

    .controller('Two', function($scope, dataService) {
      $scope.data = dataService.dataObj;
    });
```

Comment: If the function has of scope exists on and emit to call functions in another controller.